# Multiple instances of InstantSearch.js searchBox

Tags: javascript, algolia

I am trying to have multiple searchfields. This is what I am trying but it results in "cloned" input fields. Is this possible to have multiple search boxes which would work independent of each?

```
search.addWidgets([ 
        instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
            container: '#searchbox',
            placeholder: 'Regular Searchbox',
            autofocus: true,
            searchAsYouType: false,
            showReset: true,
            showSubmit: true
        }),

        instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
            container: '#searchbox-2',
            placeholder: 'Searchbox to be integrated with AutoComplete',
            searchAsYouType: true,
        })
]);
```

Any help of alternative solutions on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

same question was asked on this [forum](https://discourse.algolia.com/t/setting-up-instantsearch-with-multiple-search-boxes/11375/3)

> By wrapping the entire webpage in one InstantSearch instance, it only permits one query - that is why your multiple searchboxes all reflect the same query

therefore a possible alternative would be to create another search instance
for example

```js
const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  'appId',
  'key'
);

const search = instantsearch({   //instance 1
  indexName: 'instant_search',
  searchClient,
});

const search2 = instantsearch({  //instance 2
  indexName: 'instant_search',
  searchClient,
});
```

and then create widgets like

```js
search.addWidgets([ 
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
      container: '#searchbox',
      placeholder: 'Regular Searchbox',
      autofocus: true,
      searchAsYouType: false,
      showReset: true,
      showSubmit: true
  }),

]);
search2.addWidgets([ 
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: '#searchbox-2',
    placeholder: 'Searchbox to be integrated with AutoComplete',
    searchAsYouType: true,
})
]);
```

make sure to start them separately as well

```js
search.start();
search2.start();
```

There is a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-minsky-tqr41?file=/src/app.js) in the forum link posted above

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have been through this forum thread and this will have two independent searches. What I am trying to acheive is to have both search fields work for the same hits/results.

Comment: didn't get you. do you mean somethig like rendering the hits for both searches on the same place

Comment: Yes. So what you proposed solution will have two search fields working independently. What I want is to have two search fields work together i.e two search fields with different queries. Something like Keyword search field and Location search field.

Comment: you can have the hits to render on the same container but it will override the result getting from the last searched box. maybe you can try to put a `queryHook` to modify the search request?